# Last row of a column in excel using POI for selenium-java

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

I'm in a situation where I need to find the last row of a specific column. 
This is not the same as finding the last row of the sheet because it has to be a specific column. So I want to get the last row of column Header1 for clarity.

Hopefully, anyone already done this before and share it to me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPTW0.png)

Comment: `Excel` sheets are stored row wise. So there is no other way than iterating over all stored rows until the spreadsheet is empty in a special cell. This is shown in: [Iterate over cells, with control of missing / blank cells](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterate+over+cells,+with+control+of+missing+/+blank+cells). You would iterating the rows up to the row where the cell `cn == 0` is empty.

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter, that is what exactly I did because the comment below did not give what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per suggestion of Alex above, I have done a loop to the specific column that I want to get the last row. Checking if its empty then the row before that will the last row.

This might not be perfect but it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "./GoogleAnalyticsevent.xlsx";
    // Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));
    // number of sheets in the Workbook
    System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");
    // Sheet at index zero
    for(int i=1;i<workbook.getNumberOfSheets();i++) {
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
        for (int colnum=0;colnum<sheet.getLastRowNum();colnum++){
            // Create a DataFormatter to format and get each cell's value as String
            // System.out.print(sheet.getRow(j).getCell(1) + "\n");

            // Closing the workbook
            workbook.close();
        }

    }
```

You can Change `colnum` and get your column & sheet.getLastRowNum() will retun you the last cell number

Comment: `workbook.close();` should happen only after every operation on the workbook is done. Definitly not inside a loop